# Sketch3: Can you connect two vectors and change their colors by selecting only one?

Tags: sketch-app

Let's say I have a line graph with 30 lines, and a legend with 30 circles. Can I link the circle to a line in such a way that when I change the circle color, it'll automatically change the color of the line that is paired with it?

Comment: You might want to search for the possibility of making a 'swatch' into a 'gobal' one. I have no experience with Sketch, so I can't tell you wether it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can have shared styles, but that will only change the same property on both types of elements: either fill or stroke. So an option would be to have the circles in the legend be stroked instead of filled, like this:

[image: Shared styles on sketch]

Comment: Good thinking! I'll try it. Thanks for the reply.